# Meteor useraccounts:core role empty

Tags: javascript, authentication, meteor, atmosphere, meteor-accounts

I'm trying to learn Meteor through a video tutorial to finish the code did not get the same result. Here is the code:

```
Meteor.startup(function(){
if(Meteor.users.find().count() < 1){
    var users= [
        {
            name: "Superuser",
            email: "admin@example.com",
            roles: ['admin']
                        }
                ];

    _.each(users, function(user){
        var id;

        id = Accounts.createUser({
            email: user.email,
            password: "password",
            profile:{
                name: user.name
            }
        });

        if(user.roles.length > 0){
            Roles.addUsersToRoles(id, user.roles);
        }
    });
}
```

});

It is assumed that Meteor.roles.find.().fetch () console should appear: Object name: 'admin' _id. 'whatever'; but my pops me empty [ ].

I'm using alanning: roles from atmospherejs

*Thanks in advance.*

Comment: Are you sure you run this on server-side? Do you see the new user in the Mongo database?

Comment: Yes it is on the server side and db.roles.find () on mongo appears empty. :/

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the accounts-ui and accounts-passwords packages? It might be related to that. I suggest you to install the meteortoys:allthings to check what is wrong with your DB.

Answer (score 0):

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
    if (Meteor.users.find().count() < 1) {
      var users = {
        name: "Superuser",
        email: "admin@example.com",
        roles: ['admin']
      };
      var id;
      id = Accounts.createUser({
        email: user.email,
        password: "password",
        profile: {
          name: user.name
        }
      });
      if (user.roles.length > 0) {
        Roles.addUsersToRoles(id, user.roles, 'defaultgroup');
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: This tool looks good, @ParthRaval Toys Meteor shows: meteor.loginServiceConfiguration
Params:none

_roles
Params:none

meteor_autoupdate_clientVersion
Params:none

Comment: than you have to add in your user model
roles: {
    type: Object
  }

Comment: This worked, finally note that changes are not made because previously had created the user, just the database was removed and everything worked as it should. Thank you very much. @ParthRaval